# Windows 7 permissions cruise control

Tags: windows, windows-7, cruisecontrol.net, nant

I have cruise control with Nant running on windows 7 machine .Builds work just fine. But I have a task for which i need to start a batch process which opens up an application window (directX based application) and perform some tasks. But this nant task fails all the time , the very first call for device getdevicecaps fails .this thing works on XP. Please help!
And yes if it helps, I am unable to add any publisher tasks to the cruise control server configuration .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was not the answer you were looking for.

That's because Windows 7, Vista, and the 2008+ flavors [basically shut down the ability to open an interactive window from a service completely](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/system/sysinternals/Session0Changes.mspx).  Why?  Because opening up a UI and presenting it is a huge security risk -- someone with a lower amount of credentials could in many scenarios do tasks they weren't otherwise allowed to do.

AFAIK, the only way you can get around this is to rewrite the task.